# Is f compactly supported function if h=f*g with h,g compactly supported functions

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$, $g$, $h$ be the positive functions, where $h=f*g$. Here the symbol * denotes the convolution. My question: If $h$ and $g$ are compactly support functions, is $f$ compactly supported function? Thank so for helping.

Comment: Have you been able to make any progress on your own?

Comment: Are there some continuity assumptions? (You could take $h=g=0$ and $f=1_\mathbb{N}$.)

Comment: As pointed out by copper.hat, you definitely need to assume $h\neq 0$. If the functions are continuous, rather rough estimates of $f$ and $g$ give you your desired conclusion. If you only assume $g\in L^1$ and $f$ measurable with unbounded [essential support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)#Essential_support), you can invoke [Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem) combined with rough estimates as in the continuous case to obtain the result as well.